# Handlebars multi select helpers

Tags: javascript, html, select, handlebars.js, helper

I need help with handlebars helpers:

Selected data from database:

```
{ _id: 5b598e31f24e7f820d2d422d, key: 'c-1', name: 'C#' },
{ _id: 5b598e61f24e7f820d2d4234, key: 'node-js', name: 'Node.js'}
```

HBS generate dynamic select options:

```
{{#each tags}}
<option value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

HTML:

```
<select multiple="" class="custom-select" name="skills">
    <option value="5b598e22f24e7f820d2d422b">Javascript</option>
    <option value="5b598e29f24e7f820d2d422c">C++</option>
    <option value="5b598e31f24e7f820d2d422d">C#</option>
    <option value="5b598e61f24e7f820d2d4234">Node.js</option>
</select>
```

How add `selected="selected"` to option with the same id? Is there any elegant solution for this?

For signle select field I use code:

```
{{#select post.position.id}}
 {{#each categories}}
 <option value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
 {{/each}}
{{/select}}
```

helpers.js

```
_helpers.select =  function(selected, options){
        return options.fn(this).replace(new RegExp(' value=\"'+ selected + '\"'), '$&selected="selected"');
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper like this one to test if your string is the same :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('test', function(lvalue, operator, rvalue, options) {
    var doDisplay = false;
    var items = (""+rvalue).split("|");
    var arrayLength = items.length;
    for (var i = 0; (i < arrayLength); i++) {
        if (operator == "eq") {
            if (lvalue == items[i]) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        } else if (operator == "ne") {
            if (lvalue != items[i]) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        } else if (operator == "gt") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) > parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        } else if (operator == "lt") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) < parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        }else if (operator == "le") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) <= parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        }else if (operator == "ge") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) >= parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (doDisplay) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
});
```

Then use the helper in your HTML code like this :

```
<select multiple="" class="custom-select" name="skills">
    <option value="5b598e22f24e7f820d2d422b" {{#test name 'eq' 'Javascript'}}selected{{/test}}>Javascript</option>
    <option value="5b598e29f24e7f820d2d422c" {{#test name 'eq' 'C++'}}selected{{/test}}>C++</option>
    <option value="5b598e31f24e7f820d2d422d" {{#test name 'eq' 'C#'}}selected{{/test}}>C#</option>
    <option value="5b598e61f24e7f820d2d4234" {{#test name 'eq' 'Node.js'}}selected{{/test}}>Node.js</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The value in select options is dynamic. I'm update my question. Have you any idea how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: it seems to me that there is a 1 missing in you regexp : .replace(new RegExp(' value=\"'+ selected + '\"'), '$1 selected="selected"') seems to me better. Of course if you do as you did then you don't need the test helper.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help